# Automatic Review Test on close-vote review section has one dead give-away

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Recently I decided to start reviewing close votes like many members are expected to do. I didn't intend to review all the tags so I picked up one tag to review the questions.

As everyone would know there are random tests that pop up just so that the system can ensure we are paying attention and not reviewing just for the sake of those counts and badges.

I noticed one dead give-away that would tell someone that this is an attention test and that goes like if you are reviewing for a tag, let's say `PHP`, the review test question that will popup will not have a `PHP` tag, for me once it was `excel` and for the second test it was `c++`.

Although it doesn't sound like a big deal but I think it kills the purpose of this random testing if the reviewer gets to know beforehand that it is a test question and I must review it really.

I was able to successfully spot a review test question next time using that logic.

Comment: Thanks Mat, it does look like a duplicate but I am more interested in knowing why does the system have that give-away, shouldn't it be removed?

Comment: The audits are there to check that you're paying attention. You've noticed the tags were fishy, so you were paying attention.

Comment: But that could also mean I was paying attention to avoid being caught and keep flagging fast the other ones without really looking at the question itself. Like I could be trying to trick the system

Comment: Yep. And you can also luck out and just hit the right button without even looking at the question, let alone the tags.

Comment: All these close-votes are funny. Read below `This question has been asked before and already has an answer.`: That question ***does not have an answer***.

Comment: As you've already been told, that's a quirk of child metas. Open a feature request if you think that's enough of a problem that it needs fixing.