# Specifying tags to review in the close queue always presents an incorrect question first

Tags: bug, review-queues

Ever since I started reviewing in the close queue, I've noticed that when I specify certain tags that I want to review under "filter", the first question that pops up actually has nothing to do with the tags I specified (even though it appears to be tagged with the tag I asked for).

If I dig a little further and go directly to the question, I find that the question actually isn't tagged the way I asked for.

An example is here (and a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5550830) if it works for you):

[image: Example Close Question]

You can see at the top that I've filtered for [distributed-computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) and at the bottom it is tagged that way. However, if you go to the question: [Why is Java List traversal slower than file readline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231769/why-is-java-list-traversal-slower-than-file-readline), you'll find that it never has actually been tagged with [distributed-computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-computing).

Am I the only one who's seen this? Does everyone else just skip the first question (or just review a question they didn't ask for)?

Comment: It's a review audit. Note that it also says it has zero score in review, but 8 score in reality.

Comment: Every time I change my filter? And the review audit changes the tags?

Comment: It completely depends on when the last time you had a review audit was. The fact that it occurs when you change your filter is just a coincidence, but the longer you go without completing one, the higher your chances of generating a new one on your next review. (And yes, the review audit changes the tags to match your filter.)

Comment: I understand. I get review audits all the time and I know that they change things like the votes. It seems very strange for the audits to change the tags though since that would be something that might affect the outcome of the audit.

Comment: Are you changing the filter while the first question is still loading, or do you wait for a review to load? I've seen similar behavior, but I'm not sure if you're describing the same thing.

Comment: I'm already sitting on a question when I change the filter. I change the filter. Then a new question loads and it's wrong.

Comment: I'm having the same issue...I filter for SQL, but get questions without the SQL tag.  They are always review audits...the filter does not apply to these questions.  Kinda an easy way to determine if you are seeing a test question

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255357/automatic-review-test-on-close-vote-review-section-has-one-dead-give-away  that was also a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255349/close-audits-dont-respect-tag-filters     -- those two threads cover a lot of it...tis by design apparently, I was putting together a feature request for it before I saw these posts