# Are audits that can be spotted "robotically" detrimental to the goal of audits?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

There are ways to quickly identify audits. One that I've hit a bunch of times is to use a filter; Stack Overflow has handled this two ways. The [old way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255349/close-audits-dont-respect-tag-filters) was to just have a "review" that didn't match your tag filter. The [new](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255357/automatic-review-test-on-close-vote-review-section-has-one-dead-give-away) [way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277755/audit-adds-a-tag-to-a-question-automatically-in-a-filtered-review-queue) is to just add the tag to the question to make it look like it matches your filter. (I have a screenshot as an example at the bottom of this post.) There may be other ways, but they're not coming to mind immediately. (I'd like to hear about other ways if some are known; they may offer some different insight into this discussion.)

Anyway, the exact method of spotting an audit isn't exactly what I want to discuss here, other than to make it clear that such methods exist. The problem, as I see it, is that the audits that are quick to spot encourage everyone to "hack" (for lack of a better word) or avoid the audit system entirely.

- The question in my example is well outside of my expertise. That's why I have the filter on! As such, I can only pass this audit by sheer luck or if I realize it's an audit and then go see the status of the real question (assuming the current status is considered the "correct" one). Essentially, my best bet is to "hack" the audit system, so to speak. I could also be inclined to just Skip it, since I can't really be sure what vote will pass it. This means I might well hardly ever even take an audit.
- Since it's *very* easy to recognize as an audit, I'm not sure this audit does it's job: stop robo-reviewers. It took me about 2 seconds to realize it was an audit, and a robo-reviewer might well be willing to take 2 seconds to figure out if they should press Skip.

This gives a "robotic" way of spotting audits, making it easier for people to avoid paying attention. Maybe I've misunderstood how the audit system is *supposed* to work. Is it acceptable to "hack" the system or just Skip audits every time I see one? Do these kinds of audits do their job, or are they more harmful than helpful?

I'm aware of the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046), but this doesn't really answer the question. The question is whether it's a problem if reviewers can *mindlessly* discover it's an audit. The FAQ explicitly states that the audit system is designed to foil mindless reviewing and encourage reviewers to think.

Promised example screenshot:

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6756594

[image: Tag added because of filter, but tag makes no sense]

Comment: It catches the occasional person whose mind is on cruise control, at least.

Comment: The way I see it is that if you noticed the audit, the audit has done its job. The whole point is to stop people from blindly clicking "Leave open." If you're paying enough attention to catch the audit, then great - you certainly aren't a roboreviewer. If you had been, then you would have been review-banned after a couple of failed audits.

Comment: @AlexK In my example, blindly clicking "Leave Open" would have passed. ;) So one wonders if that's the *whole* purpose.

Comment: @jpmc26 Fair enough. This is why we have both positive and negative audits. So if you always choose one option, you'll got caught eventually. But yes, I agree with this post in general - some of the audits are not very helpful at all.

Comment: @AlexK I guess my real point is this: the review audit system is supposed to force people into thinking about what they're doing when they review. It's supposed to make quickly going through posts without giving them much thought ineffective. Audits that are so obvious that it only takes a second or two to recognize them don't do that; they just add a couple of seconds checking so you can skip them or intentionally spend a few more seconds to improve your audit record. But maybe that outcome is considered acceptable, if it's only supposed to catch *really* obvious robo-reviewers.

Comment: @jpmc26 The audits are designed to catch people who place the mouse pointer over one of the buttons (other than "Skip") and just go click, click, click, click, click, click, click, ... as fast as the system lets them. And they do catch these people.

Comment: There are currently 109 people with temporary review bans. Some of those were manually applied by moderators, but most of them get applied automatically. The review audits are catching robo-reviewers.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I (and probably others) would appreciate it if you worked that up into a full answer to confirm that yes, even blatantly obvious audits are working as intended. (It's kind of terrifying if they do.)

Comment: Do you fail this review if you would click edit (to remove the tag)? ... (I remember failing some because I clicked edit, but this was a while ago ... I haven't clicked on edit the in the close reviews)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The effect of Edit was raised recently: [One shouldn't fail an audit immediately if one clicks on edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283179/1394393).

Comment: @BilltheLizard It took me a while to figure out what it is, but something bothers me about your comment. I'm not sure if the number necessarily tells us what I really want to know. That just means that 100-some people failed review audits, but without some analysis, we don't know *how* or *why* they got the ban, do we? Additionally, how do we know that's an appropriate number, that it shouldn't be much higher or lower? (The number of people conducting reviews might be relevant there, but I don't know where to get that info.)

Comment: It could use some context, which is why it's not an answer, but it does show that audits aren't completely useless. They are stopping (at least some) robo-reviewers. Also, keep in mind that 109 is just the number of *currently* banned reviewers. Audits have been in place for many months.

Comment: One different problem with the review you posted is that the very careful super-reviewer, will notice: "Aha, they tagged this Python but it is actually about C++. The question looks just fine, but I'll edit it and remove the incorrect tag." And then I think the audit will fail because the post was supposedly fine.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm don't think you were trying to imply that I was saying this, but I think I should clarify for other readers that I'm not suggesting audits are totally useless. The question I'm raising here is: do obvious audits weaken them enough that we should care about it? If so, then it would be logical to deal with situations where audits are blatantly obvious like the one I make note of. Regardless, thanks for the info. =)

Comment: @sphanley I don't think my question is answered by that. I've made some minor edits that may make the difference more obvious. The gist is, "How does this help if you can 'robotically' spot audits?" It's also less, "Is this a bug?" and more, "Is this really helpful?"

Comment: I was surprised to be pinged on this a year later, hah - in any case, still don't see how the other question doesn't answer that. To excerpt: "TL;DR If you are paying enough attention and spending enough time on a review task to figure out that a review is an audit, then the audit has already done its job."

Comment: However, it didn't end up being marked as a dupe, so my opinion is somewhat unimportant in the end.

Comment: You do know that there is already userscripts out that can 100% detect wether or not something is an audit with a AJAX flag and then display a warning on screen if it is. This is all a bit nitpicking when such stuff is available readily.

Answer (score 0):

The term "robo-reviewer" never made sense to me. I consider the term "robo" (or "robot") to be closely related to the idea of computers, and thus computer programming. On a high level, it doesn't matter if the code pushes pixels on a screen or real physical masses.

I could create a program that always passes audits. It's super easy if you know how to scrape HTML pages. You just follow the link, and see if the post is deleted, closed, or up voted (and then follow suit). Of course I'm not planning to write a program like this. I enjoy seeing how stupid audits look `:)`.

But the people we call "robo-reviewers" do not operate the same way that my program would work. They are **zombies**, not robots. They put their mouse over a button and click as fast as possible (a program to do this is also easy to write). They could cause tons of damage if left alone.

Audits are not designed to be tricks. They are intended to address a certain problem, robo-reviewers, without tripping up real reviewers too much.

The problem with creating harder audits is [described in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272505/6083675). Audits are automatically generated based on the community's decisions. The problem is that the community has often been wrong, and bad audits are created.

Reviewing isn't something that must be perfect. If you click the "requires editing" button on a post that's not worth saving, it's not as good as clicking unsalvageable, but there's an amount of leeway in mistakes that everyone is allowed. It's up to your personal morals to decide if you will game the audit system or not.

Comment: I downvoted this because it 1) spends way too much time on the semantics of the term "robo-reviewer" (3 paragraphs), a discussion that doesn't really add any useful information, and 2) it doesn't really answer the question. The question is if audits can be spotted robotically, how is this helpful?

Comment: @jpmc26 You edited the question to include the term "robotically" after I posted this.  I will see about editing in more relevant details, too.

Comment: Yes, I did, but I didn't change the meaning of the original. It was just a clarification for all the dupe voters.

Comment: *"While there are people who are bad reviewers, but not robo-reviewers, it's not as important to catch them."* It's equally important to catch them both.

Comment: @PetahChristian I meant imperfect rather than straight up bad. I've edited that out as my last paragraph covers my point better.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in cases like this is what I would in a case like this where I don't know it's an audit. I edit the post to remove the irrelevant tag. This passes the audit, regardless of what answer the audit thinks is correct, and I can go onto the next. In the rare case that I'm wrong and it's not an audit post, I've just fixed a badly tagged post.  Win/win for everyone.

I don't think this is cheating the system. It's what I would honestly do if I saw a post tagged like that in any other context. (eg. earlier today I removed an irrelevant [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag from an [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) quesiton.)

More importantly, for me at least, they do require at least some thought. I need to spend more than two seconds to make sure the tag is really irrelevant. (eg. there was a question not long ago about generating assembly code in JavaScript.) As for the truly mindless reviewer, even two seconds of thought would be an improvement.

These tests may not be the best audit test cases possible, but given the difficultly in coming up with good test cases, they may the best that can be practically implemented. I can't see how they actually do any harm.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that at the time of writing, that edit was an instant audit fail. I suppose it's changed. It can be done in 2 seconds, though: just open the real question and see if the tag is actually there. Frankly, for this specific case, I'd much rather just see the system pull questions that actually match your filter.

Comment: @jpmc26 I've never had it fail on me in this circumstance. If I did I'd be immediately complaining about it on meta, which makes me believe that if it ever did fail like that it wasn't for long. Opening the real question and checking is an additional two seconds over the two seconds necessary to suspect that it might be audit in the first place. That really puts it beyond what any actual robotic reviewer would do. It doesn't take much to catch them. The random insertion of garbage into posts used by the edit queue audits works to catch mindless reviewers.

Comment: There's a link in the comment chain on the questions about it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283179/1394393. A mod even answered justifying the behavior.