# Questionable close audit - offtopic question with a lot of upvotes

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

The question in question is ["Media resource FILEPATH/FILENAME.mp4 could not be decoded." while trying to play h264 encoded files on Firefox 35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945870/firefox-35-h264-video).

It is used in close queue audit as a "high quality" question which has no major problems and should be left as is. When used as an audit it is also displayed with the [java] tag so it was [pretty obvious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283609/are-obvious-audits-detrimental-to-the-goal-of-audits).

As i read it, the question has nothing to do with programming or programming tools. The amount of up-votes probably indicates that some other people have this problem too, but in that case (and in my opinion) the question is still better suited for superuser/serverfault.

Just to show the system that it is wrong and I am right I proceed to close it with off-topic/general software reason and was slapped with "You didn't pass!", as expected.

The meta contains a lot of similar posts about questionable audits. Is there a better way to report such audits for review?

Comment: This question is sort of borderline, IMO. I agree that it probably isn't a very good audit question, but oh well. I'm pretty careful about reading things carefully and watching for audits, and yet I still fail them from time to time (albeit rarely). It happens. I wouldn't worry about it too much. It's pretty rare.

Comment: Also, if you disagree with an audit, the best course of action is to actually go to the post and downvote/vote-to-close it outside of the review queue. That will (hopefully) prevent it from being used in audits in the future.

Comment: The close queue contains a lot of questionable questions.  It would be a pretty useless audit if it was obvious.  "Showing the system" is pretty silly, it doesn't give a hoot.  If you don't want to be assimilated then just don't bother.

Comment: @HansPassant does the system count how many times the particular audit was failed?

Comment: SE doesn't disclose any implementation details.  They want users to train on reviewing, not on beating the system.

Comment: At a glance this looks like an end-user question, but if you read the first paragraph carefully, it's a web development question.  Someone is trying to build a website, containing a particular type of video, and they are having trouble getting those videos to play correctly in a particular web browser.  I don't know if it's a _good_ question, I'll leave that for the people who frequent those tags, but it is definitely a _bad choice for an audit_, because it's arguable.